# How to get a particular InnerText from a specific class?

Tags: vba, excel, web-scraping

```
<tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <a href="/denmark/1st-division/">1st Division 2016/2017</a>
                </td>
                    <td>
                    </td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="even">
                <td>
                    <a href="/denmark/1st-division-2015-2016/">Bet25 Liga 2015/2016</a>
                </td>
                    <td>
```

Hi guys! I would like to get this: **Bet25 Liga 2015/2016** from that source code.

```
Sub ExtractHrefClass()

    With CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
        .Open "GET", Range("D8").Value, False
        .Send
        Range("E8").Value = Split(Split(Split(.ResponseText, "<tr class=""even"">", 2)(1), "<a href=""", 2)(1), """", 2)(0)
    End With

End Sub
```

A friend gave me this macro that allows me to extract the *href* of that *"even"* class, but i need to have the **InnerText** too. where i have to change the code? Thanks :)

Comment: Please share the URL from `D8` cell.

Comment: @omegastripes http://www.soccer24.com/denmark/1st-division/archive/, today i send you an email my friend ^^

Comment: @omegastripes Sorry but i need a thing more, when the macro run an error **(Subscript out of range)** because it not find what it is looking for, i would like to go on with the next macro

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the below code:

```
Sub ExtractHrefClass()

    With CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
        .Open "GET", Range("D8").Value, False
        .Send
        a = Split(Split(Split(.ResponseText, "<tr class=""even"">", 2)(1), "<a href=""", 2)(1), """>", 2)
    End With
    Range("E8").Value = a(0)
    Range("F8").Value = Split(a(1), "<", 2)(0)

End Sub
```

Comment: @ALIENATO could you please share the URLs which gives the `Subscript out of range` error?

Comment: @ALIENATO what output is expected for the provided URL?

Comment: @ALIENATO I can't find such text `Bet25 Liga 2015/2016` on the webpage by the link http://www.soccer24.com/denmark/1st-division/

Comment: sorry, wrong link :P http://www.soccer24.com/denmark/1st-division/archive/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/132730/discussion-between-omegastripes-and-alienato).